# Send Multiple JSON Files from Directory to a REST API with JMETER

Tags: json, io, jmeter

I'm really struggling with getting Jmeter to work with sending multiple json files in Jmeter to a REST API. I have tried other questions on stack and tutorials online and none of them answer my specific requirement.

My requirement is that I will have various json messages saved to a file directory and I'm trying to use JMeter to loop through the folder, pick up the json's and pop it into a HTTP request one at a time i.e. one file = one request and view the result.

Does any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be:

1. [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/) plugin to read file names into a JMeter Variable

   [image]
2. [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read the file content

   [image]

Comment: Thank you, this method works but only for the first file in the directory, how can it process them all one after the other or all at the same time?

Comment: Just add more threads/iterations. If you need all the files to be uploaded at exactly the same moment - put the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under the [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to the number of threads in your Thread Group